# Why is this script not working as intended?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm quite new to PHP and MySQL so I thought I'd give it ago. I'm trying to make a jQuery/PHP/MySQL/Json auto-complete script.

I am following [this](http://www.jqueryautocomplete.com/jquery-autocomplete-php-mysql-json-example.html) tutorial.I'm currently focusing on the PHP side of things. Everything is set up the same near enough as in the tutorial but for some reason I keep getting

> Notice: Undefined variable: results in localhost/copy.php on line 32
>
> null

Every time I call it with something like

> localhost/copy.php?term=arr

Here's my code:

> ```
>  <?php if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) )   exit;
>       else {$term = $_REQUEST['term'];}
>
> $host = 'localhost';
> $user = 'user_test';
> $pass = 'root';
> $db = 'testing';
> $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
> mysql_select_db($db);
> $query = "SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE name LIKE '$term' "; 
>
> $result = mysql_query($query);
>
> if($result === FALSE) {
>     die(mysql_error());
> }
>
> while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
> {
>   $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);
> }
>
> echo json_encode($results); // Line 32
>
>
>
> ?>
> ```

Database
[image: My database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `while` loop that you have above the line is not running, which may mean that you're not getting any results back from the SQL query.

Comment: To add to this, you're looking for "arr" in your example, but the `LIKE` statement in the SQL query does not have any wildcards surrounding it. You may want to try `LIKE '%$term%'` and if you want case insensitive searches, use `ILIKE '%$term%'`

Comment: I keep thinking of more things to add. ;)

You may want to think of a more friendly way to handle searches with no results, which I would probably do by explicitly defining the `$results` variable above the while loop so it's always defined with `$results = array();`

Answer (score 2):

If query does not return any row $results will remain undefined. It is always a better idea to make sure a variable is initialized or assigned in the same level of coding it is used.